# Gráfico de barra con lineas achuradas de fondo [ChartJS]

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

¿Se pueden crear fondos achurados con chartjs? como puedo conseguir un estilo como la siguiente barra azul:

[image: Una barra achurada]

```
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ["#f38b4a","#f3124a","#5fba7d", "#07c"],
        },  
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```